# Kafka Consumer not able to read all message after offset commit (error=OFFSET_OUT_OF_RANGE

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

i created consumer to receive messages as batch ,
ConsumerConfig:

```
    allow.auto.create.topics = false
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = latest
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id =
    client.rack =
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = cm-persistence-notification
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 1000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Spring boot Config:

```
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> cmPersistenceListenerContainerFactory(
        KafkaProperties kafkaProperties )
    {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> containerFactory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

        Map<String, Object> consumerProperties = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
        consumerProperties.put( ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "1000" );
        consumerProperties.put( ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false );
        consumerProperties.put( ConsumerConfig.ALLOW_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_CONFIG, false );

        containerFactory
            .setConsumerFactory(
                new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                    consumerProperties, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer() ) );
        containerFactory.setBatchListener( true );
       
        containerFactory.getContainerProperties().setCommitLogLevel(LogIfLevelEnabled.Level.INFO);
        
        containerFactory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode( AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE );
        
        return containerFactory;
    }


    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin( KafkaProperties kafkaProperties )
    {
        return new KafkaAdmin( kafkaProperties.buildAdminProperties() );
    }
```

Listener Class :

```
@KafkaListener( id = "batch-listener-0", topics = "topic1", groupId = "test", containerFactory = KafkaConsumerConfiguration.CONTAINER_FACTORY_NAME )
    public void receive(
        @Payload List<String> messages,
        @Header( KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY ) List<String> keys,
        @Header( KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID ) List<Integer> partitions,
        @Header( KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC ) List<String> topics,
        @Header( KafkaHeaders.OFFSET ) List<Long> offsets,
        Acknowledgment ack )
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        handleNotifications( messages ); // will take more than 5s to process all messages

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long timeElapsed = endTime - startTime;

        LOGGER.info( "Execution Time :{}", timeElapsed );

        ack.acknowledge();

        
        LOGGER.info( "Acknowledgment Success" );

    }
```

I am using manual Acknowledgment after processing message .

I found some debug log :

[image]

In above debug log , ****fetch offset is happening before offset commit, that offset is not commited so it returning OFFSET_OUT_OF_RANGE, consumer is not able to receive any message after that , Is there any way to handle this error in consumer code or how to fetch offset only after commit ****

Comment: Is this reproducible? If so, can you share a complete, small, project that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: for loop in producer to send messages continuously , count 1000000
able to receive all message in consumer console , but failed to receive in java 
in consumer , i need to receive message and do db operation so will take some time for that , so i am committing offsets manually.
Able to receive and update db sometimes , its a sporadic failure
Producer code : https://github.com/navinas33/kafka-producer-test
Consumer code : https://github.com/navinas33/kafka-test

Comment: log.retention period is 24 hours , so messages are available in kafka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got answer :

Partition log files are deleting after some some , but consumer is still looking for deleted log files ,